# 1D Topological insulator with PT symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

Assume I have the Hamiltonian for a 1D topological insulators as:
$$H=\sin(P_x) \sigma_x+i \Delta \sigma_{y}+[1-m-\cos(P_x)] \sigma_z $$ where $m$ is the mass term, $P_x$ is the momentum and $\Delta$ is an extra term to make the Hamiltonian non-Hermitian. If I choose the time reversal operator $T=i \sigma_y K$ and the parity operator $P=\sigma_{y}$, will the Hamiltonian be $PT$-symmetric?

If you wonder what is a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34344/) and references therein.

Comment: Why don't you start by hacking out $[H,PT]$. Should be easy enough, but I'm tired.

Comment: Sorry to reopen the debate, but what the hell is a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Dani the short version is that they can be used to describe non-unitary dynamics, such as those that show up in open quantum systems

Answer (score 0):

It is the Hamiltonian of the 1D PT-symmetric SSH model in real gauge. In that case, the operators P and T can be denoted as $[1,0;0,-1]$ and $[1,0;0,-1]K$, respectively. Then $PT=K$ is commutated with the real Bloch Hamiltonian, i.e.,   $(PT)H(k)(PT)^{-1}=H(k)$.