# What is Born's rule in nonsymmetric matrix mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I suppose I have a real nonsymmetric diagonalizable matrix $A$ (for example $$\left(\begin{array}[cc]& 1 & 2\\0&-1\end{array}\right)$$).Then the eigenvectors split into right and left ones which are not transpose of the other: for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $$x_L^T A=\lambda x_L^T$$ and $$A x_R=\lambda x_R$$

So the problem I have is that I don't know what the probability of measuring $\lambda$ when the system is in state $\Psi$ is, because : $|x_L^T\Psi|^2$ seems different from $|\Psi^T x_R|^2$.

The non symmetric matrix could for example arise in the following case :
consider a symmetry of the system state : $R\Psi=\Psi$ and a symmetric operator $A'$, then
$\langle A'\rangle=\Psi^T A'\Psi$. To obtain an asymmetry we  "insert" $R$, instead of substituting, on the second $\Psi$, hence we get : $\Psi^T A' R\Psi$.
$A'R$ could then be nonsymmetric if the symmetry does not commute with the measurement operator.

Comment: Please can you add a little more detail - e.g. Probabilities of what? What is $\Psi$ and $x_L$ and $x_R$ for example?

Comment: Just thinking outloud.  Don't think a diagonalizable matrix can be no symmetric, at least with Hermitian transformations.  What transformations?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: If the operator $\hat{A}$ is a non-selfadjoint observable wrt. one sesquilinear form/[inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$, it is sometimes possible to introduce a new sesquilinear form such that $\hat{A}$ is self-adjoint wrt. the new sesquilinear form. See e.g. [$PT$-symmetric QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34344/2451).