# Quantum observables in nonstandard Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, eigenvalue, observables

Consider a Hermitian $(n \times n)$-matrix $A$, and a Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^n$, foreseen with a nonstandard inner product. (An inner product $s(\cdot,\cdot)$ is *standard* if for any two vectors $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ we have that $s(x,y) = x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n$.)

I understand that it is important in Quantum Theory that $A$ has an orthogonal base of eigenvectors, and relative to the standard inproduct, this is indeed the case.

But what about a nonstandard inproduct ? Is this property also true, or does one only work with standard inproducts in Quantum Theory ?

Comment: Are you asking about equivalents to [PT QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34344/how-does-non-hermitian-quantum-mechanics-pt-symmetric-qm-fit-in-physics)?

Comment: This [review](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/37/48/009/meta) is popular.